# .htaccess can´t access with HTTPS to my url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let me explain the what I have done.

I have this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I insert on url at browser with HTTP, I can access to my location. But if I use HTTPS, occur a error, its this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /flights/getAirport was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g Server at 10.0.0.161 Port 443
```

Why can I access with HTTPS?

Comment: Did you setup a SSL vhost on 443 with the correct documentroot and AllowOverride All for that vhost?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This will force all traffic to use HTTPS

Comment: Not working. I do this:                                                                                                                                                              <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On 
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://10.0.0.161/$1 [R,L]
     # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>                                                                                            But the eror still the same